# Best practise making users in Maria db database

Tags: database-design, mariadb, security, users

Iam creating a basic banking database to practise MariaDB, so I wanted to know what the general guidance on what kind of users you should be making and what type of privileges?

Currently I have a read only and read and write user, would this be consider good practise or should I add/remove more users?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any best practice on this which is specific to MariaDB.

You should instead be looking for best practice for banking apps and best practice for [MariaDB security](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/securing-mariadb/) more generally.

I think you should do some of these things:

- Use granular privileges. Only grant as many privileges as a user really needs.
- Use [roles](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/roles_overview/) instead of granting privileges directly to the database users. (Note that if you want a user to have all privileges from its multiple roles simulataneously, i.e. without having to do `SET ROLE` every time to switch between them, you can create a special role for the user, set this as the default role for the user, and then grant the other roles to that role.)
- Consider using [stored procedures](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/stored-procedure-overview/) and associated grants (`GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE ...`) for accessing particularly sensitive tables. You can then also write access information to an audit table.
- Create one user for each app (web app for users, mobile app for users, web app for admins, ...)
- For security reasons, database and apps should probably reside on different servers, so therefore the `host` part of the user account should not be `localhost`, but rather the IP address of the particular app server (assuming your IP addresses do not ever change).
- You should enforce strong database user passwords - consider e.g. the [simple password check plugin](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/simple-password-check-plugin/) and the [cracklib password check plugin](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/cracklib-password-check-plugin/).

There are obviously also database security concerns beyond just database users (such as encryption and using [temporal tables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/temporal-tables/)), but that is out of scope here.

Comment: SPs can also be used for selected elevation of privilege.  Cf `SQL SECURITY DEFINER` (vs `INVOKER`)